# Can I completely rewrite my app in another language after the release in the Google Play and Appstore?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile-development

I want to start writing an application using Flutter as it suits my needs at this stage. In the future, of course, I will need to build a team and applications in Java & Swift. But if I release the application now on Flutter and create a brand, will I be able to completely re-upload the application code?

Example: for Google Play - change the Flutter code to Java.

I tried googling but can't find anything...

Comment: Why would you even consider switching from Flutter to something less productive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that is alright.
This happens all the time specially when a Proof Of Concept or hackathon idea gets adopted and has to be re-written for scale.

On iOS, it is important to keep the bundle identifier same as the original app. Similar restriction will be on Android. Other than that you can overhaul the underlying stack without any issue.

Comment: What happens with the permissions the user already approved. Will he need to reapprove those, or will they be maintained? Per example, share GPS location.

Answer (score 1):

I published twice on the Play Store, the first time years ago before Flutter and the other lately made only in Flutter: the things they seem to care the most about are the format of the file you're uploading and the permissions required by your app. All the other stuff they require is to be filled manually in your app page.

I can't give you an absolute answer, but, from my experience, they don't care about how you created your apk file or your app bundle, as long the permissions and the app info you put on the app page are compliant with their policies.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, Yes.

Long answer: as long as you keep signing with the same certificate, yes.